# What is the distribution of bit counts of a binomial random variable?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, transform

Suppose I have a binomial random variable $X \sim B(n,p)$ and I apply the following bit counting operation $$Y = \operatorname{bit\_count}(X)$$

where $\operatorname{bit\_count}$ is defined in the following Python code.

```py
def bit_count(x:int) -> int:
    bits = 0
    while x:
        bits += x & 1
        x >>= 1
    return bits
```

Here is a table of values computing this function on $x \in [0, 19]$ (for your copy-pasting convenience).

| X | bit_count(X) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 3 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 13 | 3 |
| 14 | 3 |
| 15 | 4 |
| 16 | 1 |
| 17 | 2 |
| 18 | 2 |
| 19 | 3 |

Similarly, we can plot such data for $x \in [0, 49]$ to reveal a serrated pattern:

[image]

We can also consider a simulated example that gives us a sense of what the resulting distribution can look like. This was $10^4$ samples from $B(100, 0.5)$, then transformed with the $\operatorname{bit\_count}$ transform.

[image]

Because the smoothness does not apply here, we cannot consider the derivative or Jacobian for the change in variable.

How can we derive such a distribution?

Comment: Surely you need to define a functional form of the mapping from $X$ to $Y$ and not just an algorithm for getting $Y$ from $X$ for certain $x$?

Comment: @statsplease Having an algebraic expression is nice, but not necessary in general. As frank's answer shows, it is sometimes sufficient to be able to compute over a finite collection of outcomes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a well-known distribution $X \sim B(n,p)$, i.e. we know $p(x)$, and a well-defined function `bit_count`: $x\to y$ for the domain $x\in [0:n]$. Then, the distribution over the image of `bit_count` is simply obtained as
$$
p(y) = \sum_{x,\; bit\_count(x) = y} p(x).
$$

Comment: That is the sum of $p(x)$ over all $x$ that satisfy the equality $\operatorname{bit\_count}(x) = y$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: +1 I can readily see how this answer generalizes to a class of similar questions.